# How to calculate spatial accuracy (%) of the same area of two polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile

I run land use modelling for study area in 2015 (in ASCII format and convert to polygon shapefile). I also need to compare the result from the model and actual land use in 2015 (percent accuracy of overall land use, land use type A for example).

Would it be possible to do that in ArcGIS 10.1?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably two ways to do this - raster and vector.  For the raster option look into the Combine tool - http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm .  For the vector option look at the Union tool - http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm .  You haven't mentioned what sort of metric you are using, but I'd recommend looking into the remote sensing literature a bit.  The paper by Congalton is a classic - http://uwf.edu/zhu/evr6930/2.pdf , but any remote sensing textbook should work.  Overall accuracy, kappa, true skill statistic, specificity, sensitivity, are all commonly used.